# How can I find the prime numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, primes

**How can I find the prime numbers in a one-dimensional array in C++ in a simple way ??**

```
{
         int list[5];
         int i,sum = 0;

           for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
           {
            cout << "Enter The List [" << i << "]: "; cin >> list[i];
            sum = sum + list[i];
           }
                cout << endl;
                cout << "The Sum Is:" << sum << endl;

}
```

Comment: Write a function that tests if a number is a prime. Then loop through your array checking each number.

Comment: Not sure why you have posted some code that sums the numbers in an array. That code won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Emphasizing on the comment of @john:

Create a function (say `bool is_prime(int n)`).
Now check if the number n is a prime or not.

So, you need to check if each of the positive integers more than 1 before `n` divides `n` or not without leaving any remainder. There's a shorter workaround, which will greatly reduce the computational cost. Just checking till the square root of the number `n` will do. Hence the function `sqrt()` is used.
So now, our `is_prime()` function is pretty easy to build as you can see:

```
bool is_prime(int n)
{
    int i,p=0;
    for(i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            p=1;
            break;    //even if one integer divides the number, then it is composite.
        }
    }
    if(p==1)
    return false;   //The number is a composite.
    else
    return true;    //The number is a prime.
}
```

Now, you just need to pass every value of the array into this function, and your job will be done.

Also, this program can be made even better if you check for the special case of **1** which is neither composite nor prime. A suggestion is, check your array element if it is **1** or not. If not, then pass the value in the function, else just print that it is a **1**.

**NOTE:** The `sqrt()` function is available in the `cmath` library in C++ so you need to include that in your program too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sieve of Eratosthenes. Simply how it works is it iterates (from 2) through an boolean array and if arr[i] is prime (is true, i is the given number), sets every multiplicity to false.

*Start with an array filled with true*

```
Numbers   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
is prime  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

*first you have to set arr[0] and arr[1] to false, because these are not prime numbers*

```
Numbers   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16  
is prime  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

*Now, you go to 2 and set every multiplication of it to false.*
in this case 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14 16...

```
Numbers   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16   
is prime  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0  1  0  1  0  1  0
```

*Then do it for 3*
so 6, 9, 12, 15

```
Numbers   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16   
is prime  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0  1  0  1  0  0  0
```

*4 is **not prime** so you **skip it***

*5 is prime so you do the same as for 2 and 3 (10 -> false, 15 -> false etc.)*

after you use it, you can simply check if **n** is prime

```
if (arr[n] == true)
    cout << n << " is prime";
else
    cout << n << " is not prime";
```

you can find it easily on internet, for example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/) (there are some optimizations you can add, too)